# If $Imf(z)\cdot Im(z)>0, z\in U\setminus\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow f'(z)\neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a nonconstant analytic function in a neighborhood $U$ of the real axis $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\Im(f(z))\Im(z)>0, \forall z\in U\setminus\mathbb{R}.$ Then I want to prove that $f'(z)\neq 0, \forall z\in \mathbb{R}$.
Please tell me how should I proceed?

Comment: this follows from the local representation of $f$ as first $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ for $x$ real (otherrwise just pick appropriate $z$ close to the real axis to contradict the hypothesis) and if $f'(x)=0, f(x)=a+b(z-x)^n+O((z-x)^{n+1}),a,b \in \mathbb R, n \ge 2$ and one immediately finds $z$ near $x$ to contradict the hypothesis since the arguments of $(z-x)^n$ covers the full circle for both $\Im z>0$ and $\Im z<0$ since $n \ge 2$ when $z$ close to $x$

Comment: @Conrad sir please explain why $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$? and if $f'(x)=0$ then how do you conclude that $f(x)=a +b(z-x)^n+0((z-x)^{n+1}))$

Comment: added an explicit answer

Answer (score 1):

Let me put an answer: first obviously the hypothesis needs to state $\Im(f(z))\Im(z)>0, \forall z\in U-\mathbb R$

Next assume there is $y \in \mathbb R, \Im f(y) \ne 0$ then if say $\Im f(y)=c>0$ then $\Im f(z) >c/2$ for $z$ near $y$ and that is a contradiction for $z=y-i\epsilon, \epsilon>0$; similarly we deal with $\Im f(y)=-c<0$ taking $z=y+i\epsilon$, so $f(\mathbb R) \subset {\mathbb R}$

Now since for $x \in \mathbb R$ one can compute all the derivatives of $f$ by considering the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R$, it follows by induction that $f^{(k)}(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb (R)$ for any $k \ge 0$.

But if $f'(y)=0$ let $n \ge 2$ the first index for which $f^{(n)}(y)=b \ne 0, b \in \mathbb R$ from the above ($f$ is not constant by hypothesis), while $f(y)=a \in \mathbb R$

Writing the Taylor series of $f$ near $y$ we get $f(z)=a+b(z-y)^n+O(z-y)^{n+1}$. Since $n \ge 2$ there are roots of order $n$ of $i$ with imaginary parts strictly positive and negative respectively, so if say $b>0$ we can take $z=y+\omega \epsilon, \omega^n=i, \Im \omega <0$ and get a contradiction as $\epsilon>0$ small enough since $\Im f(z)=b\epsilon^n+O(\epsilon^{n+1})>0, \Im z<0$; for $b<0$ we use $\omega^n=i, \Im \omega>0$ hence we are done!